# PyQGIS API code completion not working in PyCharm In QGIS3.10 on Windows10

Tags: pyqgis-3, windows-10, pycharm

I am configuring Pycharm 2020.3 to work with QGIS3.10 on Windows.
I have followed the various instructions from previous answers. Configure the interpreter.
Pycharm recognizes Qt including autocompletion of PyQt Class.
[image]

I can also run the QGIS matplotlib by changing the aggt configuration to Qt.

I can run processing scripts
[image]

However, it does not recognize all QGIS class documentation. In the image it shows only the suggestion of the main modules.
[image]

But it does not show anything for classes, it does not recognize documentation for a class for example QgsVectorLayer.

I use this .bat file to set up and run pycharm

```
@echo off 
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=c:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.10
set path=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%WINDIR%\system32;%WINDIR%;%WINDIR%\system32\WBem

call o4w_env.bat 
call qt5_env.bat
call py3_env.bat

@echo off
path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\grass\grass78\lib
path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\Scripts
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis-ltr
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\qtplugins;%QT_PLUGIN_PATH%
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\python;%PYTHONPATH%

set PYCHARM="c:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.4\bin\pycharm64.exe"
@echo on
start "PyCharm with QGIS knowledge!" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

Comment: Same problem here qgis 3.18

Comment: Did you set "Python Interpreter" path  as `c:/qgis_path/apps/python37/python.exe` in "Create Project" window or in "Settings > Project:pythonproject > Python Interpreter"?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I did. Even when I type qgis. the autocompletion gives me the options of the core, gui and other libraries. And I can run the scripts with the above code. But the auto-completion does not show more than that. It may not be accessible, but I understand that in QGIS2 it was.

Comment: Interesting! I use PyCharm 2021.1. After specifying "Python Interpreter" path in Create Project window, autocompletion works as expected. `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\python.exe`.